# "chosen to be with" or "chosen with"

Tags: grammar

I have a function which I need to specify its parameter. I chose the parameter of this function to be close to its independence case. Then, I try to say that this function is specified with low parameter. I just wonder do I need to use "chosen to be with low parameter" or "chosen with low parameter"

Here is my try:

*This function is chosen to be with low parameter.*

*This function is chosen with low parameter.*

Which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Chosen to be with

Implies that something is supposed to be with something else, for example

> Jack was chosen to be with Lily for the project.

while on the other hand

> Chosen with

Means the way of choosing

> The pairs were chosen with a lottery.

So in your case out of the two it would be

> This function is chosen with a low parameter

But I don't think this sentence is the correct one you want overall, it's missing some contextual precedence to make it seem actually correct.